# Script to update 5500 fields in a telephone type column with random numbers

Tags: mysqli, php-7

I would need to create a php7 script that generates 5500 random telephone numbers starting with the example number 3
"3471239900". The script should go to overwrite the data already present.

```
/**
 * genera numero tel casuale che inizia per 3
 */
function telefono()
{
    $telefono = '';
    for ($k=0; $k<9; $k++) {
        //genera casuale 9 cifre
        $telefono .= rand(0, 9);
    }

    //inizia per 3
    return '3' . $telefono;
}

$res = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id_com FROM commesse ORDER BY id_com');
while ($riga = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $id = (int)$riga['id_com'];
    $query = "UPDATE commesse SET cliente=tel='".telefono()."' WHERE id_com=" . $id_com;
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: the script I posted does not work, I would like to understand how to fix it, or understand how to make an update query to run directly on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invent such code to fill a single column in a database table with random numbers.

Following update statement will populate `cliente_tel` column of the `commesse` table with 10 digit random numbers all beginning with `3`.

```
UPDATE
  `commesse` 
SET
  `cliente_tel` = CONCAT("3",ROUND(RAND()*(999999999-100000000)+100000000)) 
WHERE 1;
```

Using [ROUND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) is necessary here since [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) returns a float between `0` and `1`.

**Good to remember**: Running any kind of update/insert statement in a loop is always expensive and slow. Try to avoid running SQL queries in a loop as much as possible.